# Rails - Send emails through an exchange server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exchange-server

How does one use an exchange server to -

1. Send an email from a rails application
2. Authenticate credentials (user name / password)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about Microsoft Exchange.)

If you can use Exchange as an SMTP server then it should just be a question of configuring ActionMailer's SMTP settings appropriately. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration